# Remove elements from an eloquent query based on a condition between these elements

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an eloquent request:

```
HealthItem::where('person_id', 1)
        ->orderBy('name', 'ASC')
        ->orderBy('date_in', 'DESC')
        ->get();
```

It returns a result like this :

```
[
    {
        "id": 26,
        "name": "Test 1",
        "date_in": "2020-06-24",
        "date_end": "2020-09-24",
    },
    {
        "id": 27,
        "name": "Test 1",
        "date_in": "2020-05-19",
        "date_end": "2020-09-24",
    },
    {
        "id": 28,
        "name": "Test 2",
        "date_in": "2020-09-19",
        "date_end": "2020-09-24",
    },
    {
        "id": 32,
        "name": "Test 3",
        "date_in": "2020-09-19",
        "date_end": "2020-09-24",
    }
]
```

I would like to keep only the different items with the most recent date `date_in`. For example, keep `Test 1` with `date_in` = `2020-06-24` and remove from the results all old `Test 1` (here, the one with the `date_in` = `2020-05-19`)

Obviously, this is an example. There could be 5 or more `Test 1` but I would always keep the one with the most recent `date_in`

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `distinct` method.

```
HealthItem::where('person_id', 1)
        ->distinct('name')
        ->orderBy('name', 'ASC')
        ->orderBy('date_in', 'DESC')
        ->get();
```

Check [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#selects)